# Is there a way to see a live demo of code samples hosted on gist?

Tags: github, gist

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Is there a way to see live demos of code samples hosted on gist?

For example, is there a way to see the live version of this sample? https://gist.github.com/tmcw/3452458

I can obviously download the code and run it locally, but I was wondering if gist is actually intended to host demos as well as raw code.

Comment: Is https://gist.github.com/tmcw/3452458/raw what you want?

Comment: Thanks - no I was looking for the rendered HTML, as it would appear in the browser when run on a server.

Comment: https://gist.run/ is the non-hacky solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I knew there was a way!

Go to http://bl.ocks.org/ and add the gist ID to the end of the URL.

For example: http://bl.ocks.org/3452458 for the gist in my original question.

Comment: Good catch. +1. My answer still stands as "this is not a Github feature".

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of from GitHub.

The only example of "gist rendering" I am aware of is **[gist.io](http://gist.io/)** for rendering a blog page from a gist.
For instance, [this post](http://gist.io/3135754) is taken from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/idan/3135754).